# What is the advantage of using SSL/TLS over just handling encryption myself

Tags: sockets, ssl, encryption, websocket, cryptography

I have a simple websocket server and I currently XOR the bytes to provide simple encryption to prevent data tampering, sniffing, no AES, no other cipher algorithms - the key can be reverse engineered anyway. When I google "how to secure websockets" I get only one answer: SSL/TLS. Using SSL requires from me to generate certificates in order to use it and protocol handles encryption for me so I don't have to call my encrypt/decrypt functions myself. I don't understand the difference between those two approaches. Certificates ensure that the server we connect to is the right one am I right - they are like identification cards. But I'm confused. Do I really need SSL for my simple server? My client is written in C++, websocket server is on Node.js. I'm planning to make a webclient for it later.

Comment: Obligatory: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "*Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.*"
 SSL/TLS is correct and well vetted. The chances of creating a solution with equlivelent security is close to 0.

Comment: Note that you can get a free certificate from [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) but they expire and must be renewed every three months.

Comment: @zaph thanks for this, didn't know about let's encrypt. Now I'm reading about it and it looks like it's easy to setup!

Comment: Generating self-signed certificates is quite painful process for such a layman like me.

Comment: *Generating self-signed certificates is quite painful process for such a layman like me.* Generating a certificate is painful, but you wanted to implement your own homegrown crypto scheme?!?!?!  "I don't want to carry a bag of groceries upstairs, so I'll disassemble my car, carry it upstairs piece-by-piece, and reassemble it with the groceries in the trunk."  I guess that's why you asked.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm a programmer, not security expert. I'm reverse engineer as well and I know with access to binary when it's running it's easy to hook and decrypt things. My "homegrown crypto scheme" wouldn't require any certificates at all. It would be easier to setup but easier to decrypt.

Comment: This 
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy10660_.htm helped me to understand SSL handshake better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL/TLS is correct and well vetted. The chances of creating a solution with equivalent security is close to 0.  But perhaps you have many years of full time experience developing cryptographic solutions, but then this question would not be asked.

In answer to: "Do I really need SSL for my simple server?" Yes if you need security.

See the "Schneier's Law" comment,

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-an-ssl-connection-short-of-bruteforcing